# Centering a form horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, forms, center

I have looked for a solution to this for around half a day. I am just starting web design and I need to center a form horizontally and vertically. Right now it is in the top left-hand corner. Please do not mind the bad code I am going to tidy it up soon.

```css
form {
 
    display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
    
}


.trans {
    
    background:rgba(1,1,1,0.6);
    
}

body {
    
  background-image: url(wallpaper.jpg);     
    
}

.text {
    

    
}

.box {
    
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" sizes"32x32" href="pths_logo32x.png">
        <title>Peq Anon</title>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <input class="trans text" type="text" name="Password">
                <button type="submit" onclick="#">Submit</button>    
            </form>    
        </div>
        
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the `display: table-cell`

Comment: I did that but it only centered it horizontally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: wrap your form in a container div and use `display: flex` property to set the alignment.

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- the rest of your code comes here -->
</div>
```

And for the CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* center vertically */
}
```

## Edit

You have to make sure that the height of your `body`, `html` and `container` elements are all set to 100%.

Look at this fiddle for an example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5h4svop/2/)

Comment: Make sure that the container div spans the whole height of the document. In other words, set the height of the container div to 100%, like this ```height: 100%```

Comment: I edited my post with an example so you can get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

form {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You need to have a static form height though.
The form height:100px is the height of your form. the margin-top needs to be 50% of your form height.

Answer (score -1):

Use `margin:auto` for horizontal center
Use `top:50%` and `position:relative` for vertical align.
Don't forget to define a `height` for the container and make its position `relative` too.

```css
 form {
    margin: auto
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    
    }
    .container{
    position.relative;
    height:200px;}
    
    
    .trans {
    
    background:rgba(1,1,1,0.6);
    
    }
    
    body {
    
    background-image: url(wallpaper.jpg);     
    
    }
    
    
    
    .box {
    
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" sizes"32x32" href="pths_logo32x.png">
        <title>Peq Anon</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <form id="form">
                <input class="trans text" type="text" name="Password">
                <button type="submit" onclick="#">Submit</button>    
            </form>    
        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks any idea about how to center it vertically?

Comment: Use top:50%  for vertical center.sorry let me finish my answer.

Comment: @BilboBaggins You can run the snippet now. I edited my answer.. Hope it answer yours?